# PHP script stops on str_getcsv with no error

Tags: php, quit

Newbie here with a frustrating, but probably simple question.   I am trying to write a script that will get the last line of a .csv with 2 columns.  I only need the value in the second column to do a calculation.   I have been trying to use str_getcsv to access the second column and then calculate the math.    The script works fine on my local server but when I upload to the webserver the script stops and the rest of the page does not load.   There are no error messages.    Here is the code that I have been working with.   It gets to the hello1 echo and stops.

```
$file = "test.csv"; 
//echo "hello";
$data = file($file);
$line = $data[count($data)-1];
echo "hello1";
$dump = str_getcsv($line);
echo "hello2";
$mynum = $dump[1]*1440;
echo $mynum;
```

Comment: enable all php error on your server and might see the error.

Comment: Put this `error_reporting(-1);` at the top of your script and try it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php
>
> (PHP 5 >= 5.3.0)

What PHP version is installed on your host?

> There are no error messages.

Then [enable error reporting.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Comment: Thanks Neal and Code, it was in fact a php version issue on the server and reporting was not all on...

Comment: Thanks all, with your input I was able lookup a snippet code that checked for the str_getcsv function, and if it is not found to use an alternative.   Its all working now.  I simply added this code above the original. 

    if(!function_exists('str_getcsv')) {
    function str_getcsv($input, $delimiter = ",", $enclosure = '"', $escape = "\\") {
        $fp = fopen("php://memory", 'r+');
        fputs($fp, $input);
        rewind($fp);
        $data = fgetcsv($fp, null, $delimiter, $enclosure); // $escape only got added in 5.3.0
        fclose($fp);
        return $data;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

- Enable all php error on your server.
- Make sure that `test.csv` is readable.